# react-native-flash-message hidden by status bar on Android

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-flash-message

I am trying to display a dropdown message with [react-native-flash-message](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-flash-message) on an app using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/). The message looks great on iOS but is hidden behind the status bar on Android. I've tried modifying the zIndex and elevation values but that hasn't fixed it.

**Android**

[image]

**iOS**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try add `hideStatusBar` `statusBarHeight` you can see in [props](https://github.com/lucasferreira/react-native-flash-message#props) .
your FlashMessage  component may be like this

```js
<FlashMessage 
  hideStatusBar={false}
  statusBarHeight={StatusBar.currentHeight}
  ...
/>
```